# Changing "global" array with pool processes

Tags: python

Apologies first for the small code dump to follow, but I've spent the evening taking my first baby steps into the multiprocessing module; with my previous knowledge coming from openMPI fortran. I'm having issues with the below code in that although all the threads spawn and run etc and have access to all the correct values (both global and local) the changes each inacts upon the numpy points array do not remain. I have tried both setting the array as "global" as well as segregating into a separate class to access it both to no avail. I guess I'm missing some fundamental understanding.

Important parts:

```
points = np.ones( N )

def explore(pos,rad):
    #find range of points for comparison
    low = []
    high = []
    for dim in pos:
        low.append( int( floor( (dim - rad - 0.5*radius) / radius ) ) )
        high.append( int( ceil( (dim + rad + 0.5*radius) / radius ) ) )

    #check for overlap
    for x in xrange(low[0],high[0]+1):
        for y in xrange(low[1],high[1]+1):
            for z in xrange(low[2],high[2]+1):
                if points[x%N[0],y%N[1],z%N[2]]:
                    point = (x*radius,y*radius,z*radius)
                    distance = (point[0]-pos[0])**2 + (point[1]-pos[1])**2 + (point[2]-pos[2])**2 
                    if distance <= (rad+(0.5*radius))**2:
                        points[x%N[0],y%N[1],z%N[2]] = 0
    return

pool = Pool()
for i in xrange( atoms ):
    pos = ...
    rad = ...
    pool.apply_async(explore,(pos,rad,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: For any one interested in how to bypass this limitation I found the solution was to change the array variables in a callback function; previously storing all the points that pass the condition in explore to this via a list. I unfortunetly cannot tell you why this is the case, but its a fix none the less.

All the best, Ali

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `multiprocessing.pool`, it's not threads, it's full processes you're spawning here. The doc says:

> The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency,
>   effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using
>   subprocesses instead of threads.

EDIT: Alternatively, there's undocumented `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`, with same API as `multiprocessing.pool`. But yes, it's undocumented, which means it might break/go away etc.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to use shared objects in shared memory to get something working this way. http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects